# Can this code lead to a race condition?

Tags: java, multithreading, struts-1

I'm learning struts and I have created a `dispatchAction` that check for users privileges and then forward to the correct page.
This is the code :

```
public class UserCheck extends DispatchAction {

    private static String role = "";

    public class UserAction extends DispatchAction {


        public ActionForward checPrivileges(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            boolean isAdmin;
            //check if admin and put outputin in isAdmin
            //check if user is admin
            if (isAdmin) {
                role = "admin";
            } else {
                role = "user";
            }
               //forwared based on role
        }
    }
```

Can this code lead to a race condition since attribute role is static and shared between all the instance of `UserCheck` ?

Comment: Yes, it most definitely will lead to a race condition exactly as you describe.

Comment: Agree. This will lead to race condition. If you need to access the role somewhere down the road  consider storing it in session or request attribute. I also believe in struts/struts2 it shall be possible to pass the role as parameter to the action you are forwarding to.

Comment: *learning struts* ? S1 is EOL. Start with Struts2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will lead to a race condition if:

1. You have multiple instances of UserAction.

2. When you only have one instance of UserAction, but checPrivileges is not a synchronous method.